# Completely new pc shut down after 4-5 hours of gaming and cant run games anymore

Tags: graphics-card, power-supply, shutdown, cooling

I built a custom pc, here is the rundown of the most important parts concerning this issue:

- Gigabyte GeForce RTX 3070 EAGLE OC LHR
- AMD AM4 Ryzen 5 5600 CPU
- TUF GAMING B550-PRO
- MSI MPG A750GF, 750W PSU
- Fractal Design Meshify 2 Compact TG Light

So I played games, testing it out and it worked wonderfully. FPS were crazy at max settings, ran with no issue nor any noise, however I made a mistake and didnt keep an eye on temperature and the PC itself after a while since I got carried away.

It shut down, simply. I opened the case and the gpu and cpu were hot, but my previous computer was basically equally hot when gaming for hours on end with no issue.

I looked into Event viewer and have 1 critical (41 kernel power, task 63), and looking up it seems to be connected to the PSU most of the time. Not only that, I noticed that the pc now makes a clicking noise when shutting down whereas it didn’t before, it’s only a tiny bit more loud, and once it forcefully shuts down, it doesn’t turn back on unless I switch the PSU off and on and then turn on the PC.

I’ve only forcefully made it turn off 3 times, and once was the first time it happened, so 4 times total so far. I’m avoiding pushing it to its limits in case this can damage other parts that are otherwise healthy.

Last important note to mention, as mentioned I tried stress testing to see at what temp it turns off. I started up elden ring and barely got 5 minutes (no performance issues however) and it turns off at around 57 Celsius for the gpu. I feel the need to say that it definitely wasn’t at 57 the first time it shut off.

I played with the psu cables, where before I had 1 PCle cable going to the graphics card, I instead plugged two yet it made no difference, if slightly worse since I get barely a second into elden ring before it shuts off.

Sorry for the lengthy post, I just want answers on what to change and I need to be sure so I don’t waste money and time honestly. This has stressed me out. I did my best to narrow down what the issue is and my suspicion is PSU however I’m by no means a PC expert.

Comment: If your graphics card had two connectors but only one was fitted then it may have damaged either that voltage

Comment: Both were used but with 1 cable that had a 6 pin and 8 pin. Does it still apply?

Comment: A little, but it's far less bad. I'd be wondering if you got a bad PSU at this point. Something is overheating under load, it might not be the actual GPU chip, but it sounds like the regulators in either the PSU or GPU are not happy.

Comment: You’re right, I was debating wether the issue was with the gpu itself or the PSU. The manual I got I only found in Chinese so I couldn’t understand what slot to use, and all videos I watched used the same cable for 2 slots. How do I go about know which specifically to get it fixed? I have warranty on my gpu but will this cover it? 

Thank you for helping by the way

Comment: The only 100% way to know which part is faulty is to replace them or try them in a different machine. This kind of fault is definitely something warranty should cover on any component. My first try would be with a different PSU.

Comment: Yes, I have a sibling with a pc build quite similar to mine so I’ll try the 3070 on it and see if everything works as it should. If it does I’ll replace the psu! Thank you, also I’m relieved warranty will cover in case there’s a problem with the card haha

Comment: If the 6 & 8 pin came from the same 'wire' then they're unlikely to be able to supply enough power for both. If it needs 2x8-pin then it needs them, faking it with a single cable isn't going to be enough. [8-pin cables need to be able to provide 75W *each*]

Comment: 1) Are you sure that the CPU heatsink is attached properly? 2) Can you tell exactly where the click comes from? It is normal for a high-efficiency PSU to have a relay that bypasses an inrush current limiting component shortly after start-up, and relays click so that would be nothing to worry about.